# Creating Two Applications From One Target

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any way to create two iOS applications from one target and project in XCode?
I have searched for it and got no clear answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES**, each target is a different app. Just make additional targets, and they will have seperate build settings and plists.

You can use compiler flags to seperate them, similar to the DEBUG flag, using #if and #endif segments.